# Matplotlib wrong colorbar assigned to subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I have a wrapper, `plot2d`, for the matplotlib function `imshow` which also calls `colorbar` (see code below). When I use it on subplots in non-sequential order (e.g. subplot 2 followed by subplot 1) the wrong color bar gets plotted on at least one of the subplot axes. An example of this, is the function `bad_cb_on_top`, in the below code. However, when I use `works_just_fine` I get the intended result. The only difference between these two function is the order in which they plot to subplot axes.

My two questions are :

1. Why does the order in which I plot to subplot axes matter?
2. How can I get `bad_cb_on_top` to produce the same results that `works_just_fine` currently give, *without* modifying `bad_cp_on_top`?

Version info:

- python 2.7.3
- matplotlib 1.1.1

Example code:

```
from pylab import *

x = linspace(-1, 1, 100)
x, y = meshgrid(x, x)
data = 1./(x**2 + y**2)

def plot2d(data, ax=None, vmax=None):
  '''A simple wrapper for implot.'''
  # if ax was given, set ax as the current axis for plotting
  if ax :
    sca(ax)

  # Plot the data
  im = imshow(data, vmax=vmax, interpolation='lanczos')
  # This line assures that ax is the axis which was just plotted on
  # even if ax was not specified
  ax = im.axes

  # Add the colorbar
  cb = colorbar(ax=ax, orientation='vertical')

  return None

figsize=[4, 7]

def bad_cb_on_top():
  # This function copies the color bar from the bottom panel 
  # to the top panel for some unknown reason.
  fig, axs = subplots(2, 1, figsize=figsize)
  plot2d(data, vmax=31, ax=axs[1])
  plot2d(data, vmax=314, ax=axs[0])
  fig.show()

def works_just_fine():
  # This function works as intended despite little change
  fig, axs = subplots(2, 1, figsize=figsize)
  plot2d(data, vmax=314, ax=axs[0])
  plot2d(data, vmax=31, ax=axs[1])
  fig.show()

bad_cb_on_top()
works_just_fine()
```

Output from `bad_cp_on_top()`:

[image: Output from <code>bad_cp_on_top()</code>]

Output from `works_just_fine()`

[image: Output from <code>works_just_fine()</code>]

Comment: Can't reproduce in `1.3.1`, both function gives the latter one.

Comment: Interesting this could be a bug in matplotlib 1.1.1. Does this count as an answer (assuming updating matplotlib fixes it for me)?

Comment: Current me stopped by to give past me a hard time for using "jet".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be *very* wrong, but you may be able to enforce the right one by passing im into colorbar() as the mappable.  In plot2d:

```
cb = colorbar(im, ax=ax, orientation='vertical')
```

I think that way it specifies not only the axes but the mappable input.  FYI, it makes no difference to me (using 1.3.1) so nothing breaks, but it also means I can't test it.